# Select a file and get its path and filename

Tags: vb.net, explorer

Using VS 2013 and vb.

I have a web page and on a button click i would like file explorer to open so the user can navigate to a folder location and highlight a file.  The web application will then get the path and filename of the file.  Just to be clear I dont want to open the file I just want the details.

I cant seem to find a way of doing this, can you help?

UPDATE

Apologies perhaps I havent explained my self very well.

This is so a user can reference a document saved on a file share with a particular audit (the web page is for recording audits).  Therefore they will click a button and file explorer will open.  They will navigate to a folder (will be different everytime) and select a file.  File explorer will then close and the web application will know the path of the file and its name.  I can then use this to create a link on the web page to that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting directory path use; `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)`

For file name `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)` or `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)`

more info is available at http://www.dotnetperls.com/path

Answer (score 0):

Use `path.getFullPath()` method to get the file path as a string.
If you want to get the file name only use `path.getFileName()` method.